# Conversion of data passed as inputstream (text file transferred in binary mode thru postman API) to String in Java

Tags: java

I have a text file that have blanks in between (sample data below)

```
11  2476 09201607201607312016013120175200196701    101
```

This text file is passed as binary through an API gateway to a Java lambda function as an input stream. I would like to convert this to a string inside the Java function.

I tried this:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
String result= StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)).toString();
Sysout.out.println(result);
```

But when it prints, multiple blanks in between are skipped from conversion retaining with single blank.

**printed**

```
'11 2476 09201607201607312016013120175200196701 101'
```

**original**

```
'11  2476 09201607201607312016013120175200196701    101'
```

I would like to get it to display as original.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

Comment: You will need to find out if that whitespace was already gone before it got to the service or not. There is nothing in Java that will make those spaces magically go away.

Comment: `IOUtils` is from Apache Commons?

Comment: Yes, from Apache Commons

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem, see https://bpaste.net/show/0b2ba52c0c27. The result equals the original. Something changes your input stream before you can read from it.

Comment: `[help-me]` Are you using tabs? Different tab stops? Another thought is that the problem is likely on the sending end. Please look carefully at your received bytes in the debugger  and see if the expected spaces are there. For simplicity, try sending text that consists of nothing but spaces.

Comment: white spaces are there in when it reaches the service, because i am also uploading this file from Lambda function to S3 bucket. Once i open it there, i can see the contents as original with all white space in between

Comment: not using any tab. as i mentioned earlier i am getting the original file contents after I upload this inputstream to S3 bucket from the same function

Comment: Then please use the debugger to look at the bytes. For the future, to make a commenter aware that you responded, use @commenterName (e.g. @Arkadiy).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the lambda Java function i am executing. The text file is passed as binary inputstream to this function.

when i upload this inputstream to AWS S3 bucket in the same function, i am able to get whitespaces same as original.

Only when i try to convert to String within the same function, the extra whitespaces in between values are getting skipped

```
@Override
         public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream 
                                      outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
                LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
                AmazonS3 s3Client = s3ClientSetup();
                ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();

                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
                String result= StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)).toString();
                logger.log(result);

                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                metadata.setContentType("application/text");
                metadata.addUserMetadata("title", "sample");
                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileObjKeyName, stream, metadata);
                request.setMetadata(metadata);
                s3Client.putObject(request);
                logger.log("File Uploaded");
          }

         private AmazonS3 s3ClientSetup(){
                String clientRegion = "********";

                BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("**", "***");

                AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                            .withRegion(clientRegion)
                            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                            .build();
                return s3Client;
            }
```